# Hp Pavilion dv6000 wont boot right and freezes

Tags: boot, laptop, memory, hp-pavilion

I have an hp pavilion dv6000 that was having windows issues recently including randomly freezing. I eventually concluded that the hard drive was bad (And I was correct as the bad drive started making funny noises and quit working soon after). So I replaced it with a known good drive and put windows on it and it worked for a few hours.

After a few restarts startup didn't even make it to the login screen. It just stays at a lighted black screen until I restarted. After another restart it made it to windows but then froze after a few minutes. A few more restarts yielded one of these two results.

Like I mentioned earlier I have a know good drive in it and I also replaced the memory that was in it with a know good stick along with running memtest with no errors.

So What does that leave? a corrupted windows installation? Motherboard? CPU?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell exactly why or what's happening there, but there are few more things you might consider doing to identify what might the culprit be.

- If the hard drive is portable and you have a different computer, you might want to try and see how it goes over there.
- If it boots up something is wrong with your laptop itself, if it doesn't then it could either be the hard drive (Yes, I remember you mentioning it being a good hard drive) or corrupted OS. To check one of these two, you could consider reinstalling windows or ubuntu just to see if they boot up or not.
- If its the problem with the laptop then I have nothing to say since you have already carried out the memtest. HP laptops heat up pretty bad after a year or so, I had two from the dv series, and I have had enough. Once when I was having the problem of restarting after certain time while installing windows, I cranked my AC to the coolest settings and put the laptop right on top of it, and had the installation completed. Yes and the laptop is still running, but after using for 3 or more hours it needs a break, well. If you don't mind you could give that a try as well.

I would first try putting it right on top of the AC with the coldest setting and see, just because its easy.

Good luck and let us know. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to format your answers so they're easier to read.

Comment: @Arsenish giving you this accept because of what you said about the ac thing. It was indeed a heat issue as a fan was malfunctioning!